# How to build ionic / angular app using docker

Tags: angular, docker, cordova, ionic-framework, dockerfile

I have an ionic / angular / cordova application, and I'm trying to use Docker to create an apk. The docker file is in a sub-sub folder (because I intend to have several docker files for various un-related tasks). How can I get the docker to use the ionic code that is 2 directories up?

Here is my project structure (I'm on MacOS). "/path/to/" is actually something like /Users/[my name]/Documents/ionic-project/

```
/path/to/e2e
/path/to/gen
/path/to/google_services
/path/to/node_modules
/path/to/out
/path/to/platforms
/path/to/plugins
/path/to/resources
/path/to/scripts
/path/to/src (contains my angular code)
/path/to/typings
/path/to/config.xml
/path/to/ionic.config.json
.... several other individual ionic-related files
```

then, I also have:

```
/path/to/docker
```

and within this "docker" folder, I have sub-folders for each Dockerfile, e.g.:

```
/path/to/docker/android/Dockerfile
/path/to/docker/ios/Dockerfile
/path/to/docker/othertask/Dockerfile
etc..
```

My docker file contains all the required tool installations for Android (Gradle, JRE, Android tools, etc.) and all that seems to be working.

At the end of the docker file, I have:

```
WORKDIR
RUN npm install
```

I suspect that I need to change WORKDIR and maybe do a COPY command to get the source files somehow (or, maybe pull from Git repo?), but nothing that I've attempted works.

In essence, I am hoping to run a single docker command that builds an APK files with the existing ionic files that exist a couple of directories "up" from it.

Comment: Did you find any solution for the issue?